# Uses for Work Orders

Tags: servicecloud, spring16, work-order

I'm excited by Work Orders, but only if they add improved reporting or trackability.  I would love to see something like Taskray's or Jira's boards on WorkOrders, and to be able to report on our speed of quality service delivery.  Are these pieces in existence/development, either by SFDC or by a third party vendor?

We do not use `Asset`s, `Entitlement`s or `Contract`s, but I see these as a way to move off `Task`s for client-facing work.  If they offered better reporting - say, report on average length of time in `Assigned` status for a particular type of WorkOrder or Case, it sounds useful.

I am not sure if they add this functionality or if those are perhaps planned but not implemented.  Should I expect WorkOrder to replace `Task` in this way and with these improvements?

Comment: I love it. Excited by a feature that you currently do not see a benefit in. As it stands this question is too broad. Try to narrow it down to a more specific question.

Comment: @Eric I explained more specifically what I was excited by.  Any better?

Answer (score 0):

[Salesforce Spring ’16 Release Notes > Service > Field Service > Go Forth, Field Technicians: Introducing Work Orders (Generally Available)](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_field_service_work_orders.htm)